# How to use Typeconverter in android room

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

Ok this will be too beginners question but still.
Suppose I have created a **Converters.kt** class as

```
 class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
        return value?.let { Date(it) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
        return date?.time?.toLong()
    }
}
```

And also added  `@TypeConverters(Converters::class)` in my database class.

Now what next. How to access `dateToTimestamp` and `fromTimestamp` in my codes.
*Some demo app will be helpful*

Answer (score 3):

You have to use this converter in your entity class using @TypeConverters annotation. After that when you query on this entity (table) room will automatically use dateToTimeStamp or fromTimeStamp for converting unknown data type into known data type i.e when you save the date in db, it will be converted into Long using dateToTimestamp and when you query date then it will be converted to Date from Long using fromTimestamp by room library itself.

Comment: Ok the respective method is called by room itself. We should not care about that?

Comment: One more question what should be the variable type in the Entity Date or Long?

Comment: You want to save Date, so it should be Date.